# How to reference a particular JSON in a function call

Tags: javascript, json, function, reference

I have two javascript routines.. the first one declares some JSON and it contains a function that takes two arguments, the first argument being the json object that needs traversing and the second argument is the tab that the rendering is done in. The second routine merely passes the name of the JSON that needs traversing and tab to render in. The code is below....

```
<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">

var arr = [ {"id":"10", "class":"child-of-9", "useless":"donotneed"}, {"id":"11",    "class":"child-of-10", "useless":"donotneed"}];
var arrtwo = [ {"id":"12", "class":"child-of-12", "useless":"donotneed"}, {"id":"13", "class":"child-of-13", "useless":"donotneed"}];

function render_help(json,tab){
var html='';
    for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++){
        var obj = json[i];
        for(var key in obj){
            var attrName = key;
            var attrValue = obj[key];
            if (attrName == "id"){
                html = html +'<B>'+attrValue+'</B>'+'<BR><BR>';
            }else if (attrName == "class"){
                html = html + attrValue + '<BR><BR>';
            }
        }
    }
document.getElementById(tab).innerHTML=(html);
}
</script>

<script language="JavaScript1.2" type="text/javascript">
render_help(arr,"helptab");
</script>
```

Various testing and strategically placed alert boxes indicate that the tab parameter is being passed and interpreted correctly.

The JSON object remains elusive. For the purposes of this scripting I need the JSON "arr" to be iterated over. I feel like the answer is fairly obvious so far no luck.

Admittedly I am new with Javascript and I am apparently missing something. Does anyone have a clue as to what I'm overlooking here?

Happy New Year to you all!
Janie

Comment: Seems to work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/Vmhd4/

Comment: @somethingkindawierd: I just took the render_help call out of the separate javascript block and put it in the same one with the json data and BAM! Works like a champ! I need to give you credit for the correct answer so resubmit your answer as a solution so I can give you the answer karma. THANK YOU SO MUCH! JW

Comment: PS Do not use `for ... in` to iterate over arrays. Also: arrays full of JS objects are not "JSON". A big string with markup that looks like a JS literal is JSON; what you have is not.

Answer (score 1):

here's the answer: jsfiddle.net/Vmhd4

Looks like the difference is the `render_help(arr,"helptab");` being in the same  tag.